# Multi row header datagridview?

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

How can I create a multi header data gridview in c# Windows Application
as shown in the following image?

[image]

Is it possible to achieve same functionality in list view?

Comment: we are trying it on Winforms ..

Comment: we have tried to redraw the rectangle above the specified columns.For ex multiply the Employee column rectangle by 2 and redraw another rectangle spaning above employee and employer with the text "Rate on Reg pay/Ded. Amount",
But problem arises when gridview is repainted

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/531577e8-0be3-406d-a81b-48f8ed02e8df/
Is there any better way to achieve this functionality.